# Change path for JAXB xml generation under tomcat directory

Tags: tomcat, jaxb

I am generating an XML file dynamically in the tomcat server, I need to provide the XML file link in the JSP page to make it downloadable. I am using simple JAXB for XML generation, but XML file is not getting generated in tomcat directory. Please help.

```
            private static final String FILE_NAME = "jaxb-test.xml";

            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(test.class);
            Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();

            m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);

            // Write to File
            m.marshal(emp, new File(FILE_NAME));
```

Answer (score 0):

using spring Rest, I did this by returning `return new HttpEntity<byte[]>` using @ResponseBody and http headers.